# Rails Model After Update Get Changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working with an analytics like system and would like to send model attribute changes to it whenever they occur

Assuming I have something like this:

```
after_update :my_update_method
def my_update_method
   #send update changes to analytics system
end
```

Is there a way within `my_update_method` to get what model attributes changed? Vs. sending the entire model every time which seems inefficient

Comment: There are bunch of functions that you can use. 'object.changed?' returns if something was changed or not. 'object.previous_changes' returns changed attributes. you can see the document which function will work for your use case https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-previous_changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can select your rails version first and try
https://jetrockets.com/blog/rails-5-2-changes-in-callbacks

ex :

```
class Book
 after_update :my_update_method
 def my_update_method
  #send update changes to analytics system in Case Rails 5
  values = saved_changes
  p values
 end
end

Book.last.update(title: "Hello")
# Output 
{"title"=>["s", "Hello "], "updated_at"=>[Sun, 13 Nov 2022 22:34:33 UTC +00:00, Sun, 13 Nov 2022 22:37
```

Good luck